# BFG Repo-Cleaner - How to delete folders except some folders

Tags: git-rewrite-history, bfg-repo-cleaner

How to delete folders except some folders?

My command is

`java -jar ../BFG_Repo-Cleaner/bfg-1.13.0.jar --delete-folders "!(folder1|folder2|folder3)"`

I want all folders except folder1, folder2 and folder3.

Answer (score 1):

There is no workaround for this with BFG, you'll have to explicitly mention all the folders you want to delete from history.

Example - `java -jar ../BFG_Repo-Cleaner/bfg-1.13.0.jar --delete-folders "{Folder1,Folder2,Folder3}" YourApp.git`

NOTE: Make sure you have different names for different folder, as BFG doesn't care about the path it will delete the folders with the associated name.

> --delete-folders   delete folders with the specified names (eg
>   '.svn', '*-tmp' - matches on folder name, not path within repo)